# R Quasiquotation Built-In function aggregations

Tags: r, function, dplyr, aggregate

Below is code being drawn from a built-in dataset called `starwars`. The goal is to be able to build a final dataset object named `filtered_starwars` which is 'grouped by', 'summarized by' by pre-specified conditions (inputs) by the end-user. The end goal is to be able to create an RShiny app with this code.

However, before getting into that, there are some current problems. I have created a list of `aggregating_choices` of `mean` and `median` and `measures_choices` of `height` and `mass`. The goal is to feed this into a function called **`aggregate_statement`** that would then be called out from the final `filtered_starwars` final dataframe with the pre-specified inputs. Unforunately, I'm not allowed to do that in the `summarise` part.

I would like to create a final dataframe that would do the appropriate 'group bys' for **`hair_color`**, **`skin_color`**, **`eye_color`** (meaning that they are unique), and the new specified measures of `height` and `mass` to be created as the following columns, **`mean_height`, `median_height`, `mean_mass`, `median_mass`** for the respective subgroups.

Currently, the group bys aren't unique and the aggregate functions of mean and median don't pop up.

I would really appreciate any support or guidance! Thank you!

```
hair_color_choices <- unique(starwars$hair_color)
skin_color_choices <- unique(starwars$skin_color)
eye_color_choices <- unique(starwars$eye_color)
hair_color_selection <- c("brown", "black", "white", "none")
skin_color_selection <- c("fair", "dark", "white")
eye_color_selection <-  c("blue", "brown", "yellow")

dimensions <- colnames(starwars)[!sapply(starwars, is.numeric)]
measures <- colnames(starwars)[sapply(starwars, is.numeric)]
dimensions_groupBy <- c("hair_color", "skin_color", "eye_color")

aggregating_choices <- c(
  "mean" = mean(measures),
  "median" = median(measures)
)

measures_choices <- c("height", "mass")

aggregation_statement <- function(aggFunc, measures) {
  expr(aggregating_choices(!!enquos(measures_choice), na.rm = TRUE))
}

filtered_starwars <- starwars %>%
  filter(
    hair_color %in% hair_color_selection,
    skin_color %in% skin_color_selection,
    eye_color %in% eye_color_selection
  ) %>%
  group_by(!!!syms(dimensions_groupBy)) %>%
  summarise(!!!syms(measures_choices)) %>%
  collect() %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understood your question correctly. Is the following what you had in mind? For this I make use of the new `across` from `dplyr` 1.0.0 and the fact that you can provide the column names as strings with `all_of`, so you don't have to deal with non standard evaluation:

```r
library(dplyr)

hair_color_selection <- c("brown", "black", "white", "none")
skin_color_selection <- c("fair", "dark", "white")
eye_color_selection <-  c("blue", "brown", "yellow")

dimensions_groupBy <- c("hair_color", "skin_color", "eye_color")
measures_choices <- c("height", "mass")
aggregating_choices <- list("mean" = mean, "median" = median)

starwars %>% 
  filter(
    hair_color %in% hair_color_selection,
    skin_color %in% skin_color_selection,
    eye_color %in% eye_color_selection
  ) %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(dimensions_groupBy))) %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(measures_choices),
                   aggregating_choices,
                   .names = "{fn}_{col}"))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'hair_color', 'skin_color' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 7
#> # Groups:   hair_color, skin_color [6]
#>   hair_color skin_color eye_color mean_height median_height mean_mass
#>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 black      dark       brown            182.           183        NA
#> 2 black      fair       brown            173            173        NA
#> 3 brown      fair       blue             185.           183        NA
#> 4 brown      fair       brown             NA             NA        NA
#> 5 none       dark       blue             184            184        50
#> 6 none       dark       brown            188            188        84
#> 7 none       white      yellow           233            233        NA
#> 8 white      fair       blue             167            167        NA
#> 9 white      fair       brown            193            193        80
#> # ... with 1 more variable: median_mass <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>